# How can I change the structure of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I change the structure of a dataframe?  I need series data of each row. I tried unstack but failed.

Example dataframe:

```
    df:

        c1   c2     c3

   0     a     b     c
   1     d     e     f
```

Output Series:

```
S1 
0   a
1   b
2   c

S2
0   d
1   e
2   f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose the data frame, and, if you so like, rename the indices, to a range:

```
dfT = df.T
dfT.index = pd.RangeIndex(dfT.shape[0]) # Rename the indicies
dfT.columns=['S{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(dfT.shape[1])] # Rename the columns
dfT.unstack()
```

Comment: `pd.RangeIndex(dfT.shape[0])` is more flexible.

Comment: Indeed, I will update my answer.

Comment: And `dfT.columns=['S{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(dfT.shape[1])]` takes care of the columns.

Comment: @DYZ This is turning into your answer, rather than mine, but thanks for the comments. :-)

Comment: But whocarez? :)